# Calculate integer elements count in the mixed-typed list for full depth:

Tags: python, python-3.x

["1", 1, "abc", 123, 124.6, ['123', 1, 45], (1, 2), 3456, 567]
How to Calcualte??? There is some one who can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: a = ['1', 1, 'abc', 123, 124.6, ['123', 1, 45], (1, 2), 3456, 567]                                      for i in range(len(a)):
 print(len(a))

Comment: Do you also count `"1"` (convert to integer and count it) or you do not count it because is a string?

Comment: no, i dont count, because is a string it

Comment: Please add your code to question.

Comment: Calculate integer elements count in the mixed-typed list for full depth:             ["1", 1, "abc", 123, 124.6, ['123', 1, 45], (1, 2), 3456, 567]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it recursively:

```
def count_ints(data):
    counter=0
    for element in data:
        if type(element) == list or type(element) == tuple:
            counter+=count_ints(element)
        elif type(element)==int:
            counter+=1
return counter
```

call:

```
print(count_in`enter code here`ts(["1", 1, "abc", 123, 124.6, ['123', 1, 45], (1, 2), 3456, 567]))
```

output:

```
8
```

Comment: if you meant to make a sum of them just replace the counter+=1, with counter+=element

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_int_recursive(obj):
    count = 0
    if isinstance(obj, int):
        return count + 1
    try:
        for i in obj:
            if not i == obj:
                count += count_int_recursive(i)
    except TypeError:
        return count

integer_elements = count_int_recursive(values)
```

Comment: With the list from OP and your code I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: without function, can i solve this problem?

Comment: @b-fg Updated - didn’t account for 1 length strings that will loop forever

Comment: @GrigorNurijanyan: Why in the world do you want to solve your problem without a function? If you want to search "full depth" that will almost definitely require a recursive function.

Comment: @N Chauhan now I get only `1`...

Comment: @RoryDaulton because I have not yet passed def function